# How do you create a ScrollBar using FXML in javafx2?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fxml

**EDIT**
I was looking for a "ScrollPane" not a ScrollBar.

```
<ScrollPane  fitToWidth="true" fx:id="sasd">
<content>
    <VBox prefWidth="200" alignment="center" fx:id="Left">
        <children>
             <Label alignment="center" fx:id="gcProgramLine" text="g0x100 y123 z23"/>
```

Everything works just fine.

I have a VBox that I want to add MANY Labels to.. I would like the VBox to have the ability to "scroll" as these lines are added.

Right now this is what my FXML looks like.  Its in a BorderPane.. However I have omitted the irrelevant portions.

```
<left>
    <VBox prefWidth="200" alignment="center" fx:id="Left">
        <children>
            <ScrollBar orientation="VERTICAL" fx:id="sasd">
              <children>
             <Label alignment="center" fx:id="gcProgramLine" text="g0x100 y123 z23"/>
             <Label alignment="center" fx:id="gcProgramLine" text="g0x121 y13 z23"/>
             <Label alignment="center" fx:id="gcProgramLine" text="g0x10 y113 z23"/>
             <Label alignment="center" fx:id="gcProgramLine" text="g0x100 y123 z23"/>
             <Label alignment="center" fx:id="gcProgramLine" text="g0x100 y123 z23"/>
             <Label alignment="center" fx:id="gcProgramLine" text="g0x100 y123 z23"/>
             <Label alignment="center" fx:id="gcProgramLine" text="g0x100 y123 z23"/>
             <Label alignment="center" fx:id="gcProgramLine" text="g0x100 y123 z23"/>
             <Label alignment="center" fx:id="gcProgramLine" text="g0x121 y13 z23"/>
             <Label alignment="center" fx:id="gcProgramLine" text="g0x10 y113 z23"/>
             <Label alignment="center" fx:id="gcProgramLine" text="g0x100 y123 z23"/>
             </children>
             </ScrollBar>
        </children>
    </VBox>
```

However this gives me error and compile and will not work.  I have tried to remove children as well.  No luck..  Any thoughts?  I find it hard to find the "FXML" way to do things in Javafx 2.0.  Using code is pretty easy...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ScrollPane` doesn't have property `children`, it has `content` of type `Node`. Next fxml will work for you:

```
<ScrollPane fx:id="sasd">
    <content>
        <VBox prefWidth="200" alignment="center" fx:id="Left">
            <children>
                <Label alignment="center" fx:id="gcProgramLine" text="g0x100 y123 z23"/>
                <Label alignment="center" fx:id="gcProgramLine" text="g0x121 y13 z23"/>
                <Label alignment="center" fx:id="gcProgramLine" text="g0x10 y113 z23"/>
                <Label alignment="center" fx:id="gcProgramLine" text="g0x100 y123 z23"/>
                <Label alignment="center" fx:id="gcProgramLine" text="g0x100 y123 z23"/>
                <Label alignment="center" fx:id="gcProgramLine" text="g0x100 y123 z23"/>
                <Label alignment="center" fx:id="gcProgramLine" text="g0x100 y123 z23"/>
                <Label alignment="center" fx:id="gcProgramLine" text="g0x100 y123 z23"/>
                <Label alignment="center" fx:id="gcProgramLine" text="g0x121 y13 z23"/>
                <Label alignment="center" fx:id="gcProgramLine" text="g0x10 y113 z23"/>
                <Label alignment="center" fx:id="gcProgramLine" text="g0x100 y123 z23"/>
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </content>
</ScrollPane>
```

Comment: One would think that `ScrollPane` is a subclass of `Pane`, but it is not. Instead the hierarchy (as of Java 8) is `ScrollPane` < `Control` < `Region` < `Parent` < `Node` (where < means extends). None of these classes takes the protected method  `Parent#getChildren()` and makes it public like `Pane` does.